# Wrong linear regression computing

Tags: pgfplots

I've just started to use pgfplot and I'm actually trying to get the equation from a plot, with the linear regression. However, I'm working in a loglog plot, and the resulting regression equation is wrong (excel is right).

I'm wondering how to correct it, it should be : 0.734*x + 7e-10, not 1*x + 0.42

Thanks for your help !

that is the japan.dat

```
Q P1 P2
1.00E-07 3.01E-07 7.38E-08
1.00E-06 2.95E-06 7.35e-07
1.00E-05 2.95E-05 7.34E-06
```

and the .tex :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} % this must go first, there are many different classes
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{loglogaxis}[
height=10cm,
width=10cm,
title=Required pumping speed,
xlabel=Q (mbar.L.s$^{-1}$),
ylabel=P (mbar),
ymin=1e-8, ymax=1e-3,
minor y tick num=1,
legend entries={P$_1$(50 L.s$^{-1}$),P$_2$(50 L.s$^{-1}$),$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
\pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}]
\addplot[color=red,dashed]
    table[x index=0,y index=1] {japan.dat};
\addplot[color=red]
    table[x index=0,y index=2] {japan.dat};

\addplot table[
no marks,
red,
x index=0,y index=2,
y={create col/linear regression={y=P2}}]
{japan.dat};
\end{loglogaxis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is in the file : japan.dat ?

Comment: Edited the topic !

Comment: Please put in you MWE, all that is needed to run the code :
from `\documentclass`to `\end{document}`

Comment: What it MWE exactly ?

Comment: Minimum Working Example (MWE)

Answer (score 1):

Your data appears to be on a line in log coordinates.

Consequently, we can verify the regression line by means of simply math: the slope has to be (y1-y0) / (x1-x0) -- in log coordinates. I used `gnuplot` to compute this for the first two lines in your data file to get

```
print (log(7.35e-7) - log(7.38e-08))/(log(1e-6) - log(1e-7))
0.998230977261152

gnuplot> print log(7.38e-08) - 0.998230977261152 * log(1e-7)
-0.332324732095135
```

which is consistent with what pgfplots reports:

[image]

Are you sure you have the correct data file?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{loglogaxis}[
height=10cm,
width=10cm,
title=Required pumping speed,
xlabel=Q (mbar.L.s$^{-1}$),
ylabel=P (mbar),
ymin=1e-8, ymax=1e-3,
minor y tick num=1,
legend entries={P$_1$(50 L.s$^{-1}$),P$_2$(50 L.s$^{-1}$),$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
\pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}]
\addplot[color=red,dashed]
    table[x index=0,y index=1] {japan.dat};
\addplot[color=red]
    table[x index=0,y index=2] {japan.dat};

\addplot[red] 
    table[x index=0,y index=2,
        y={create col/linear regression={y=P2}}]
{japan.dat};
\end{loglogaxis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```